# Are there any tools to assist in creating server-side traces?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, trace

Defining a new server-side trace in SQL Server using the available stored procedures (`sp_trace_create`, `sp_trace_setevent`, `sp_trace_setfilter`) seems to be quite a tedious process.

I'm looking for a tool that provides a nice GUI (probably similar to that in SQL Server Profiler) to help with definition of traces, but for those on the **server side** rather than the client side.

Does such a tool exist?  I suppose it would be very similar to Profiler, but would set a file path for the trace file, rather than having the results returned directly to the tool.

I want to do a server-side trace as this is a production server with a very high throughput of transactional data, and I am concerned about the potential effect on performance if I use Profiler.

Comment: what version of SQL Server?

Comment: There is an option to export the trace definition from profiler, under File->Export->Script Trace Definition, though I'm not sure if that is a recent addition to the profiler app or not, I do recall using it with 2008 R2. Edit: Seems it's been there since at least 2005 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293613.aspx

Comment: @StuartAinsworth: 2008 R2, will tag

Comment: @KevinDahl: that's very useful; I will use that unless someone answers my question with some other magical tool that automates it.

Comment: @KevinDahl: I don't think I am going to get a better answer; if you put yours as an answer I'll accept it in a day or two.  Thanks!

Comment: In a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17574008/330315) [Express Profiler](http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com) was mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, there is an option in the profiler app to export a trace definition. The details of doing so are outlined on technet here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293613.aspx

The main caveat is that you have to start the trace before it can be scripted out, but you should be able to do this on a server separate from the one you actually mean to run the server side version of the trace on.